# pdp8 mri instruction(s) on a page boundary

Tags: assembly, instruction-set

Does anyone know how the pdp8 hardware (and does it vary by model) handles the mri instructions on a page boundary.  If your instruction is at address 0177 for example the program counter is used to read that instruction then increments essentially.  If you specify the current page for the address is that going to use page 0, the page of the instruction or page 1 the page where the pc is after it has read the instruction but before finished executing?

Comment: +1 for a PDP-8 question!

Comment: thanks, like the pdp-11, it is a nice and educational architecture.

Comment: Let me guess - you're writing a PDP-8 emulator on the Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: one step at a time...generic command line, then later maybe put it in front of the raspi hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [MACRO-8 Programmers reference manual for the PDP-8 family computers](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/dec/pdp8/software/DEC-08-CMAB-D_MACRO8.pdf) the mention *family* in the title suggests that the multiple models all presented a common architecture to the programmer.

From [HD-6120 CMOS high speed 12 bit microprocessor](https://www.grc.com/sn/files/HD6120_Specifications.pdf), the PC is incremented at the beginning of the instruction, but copied to the OL (Output Latch) first. This implies the current page refers to that of the instruction. The reference is in any event a valuable source of an executable description of the processor.

Douglas Jones' [The Digital Equipment Corporation PDP-8 Frequently Asked Questions](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/pdp8/faqs/) explains that typical assemblers did not provide any way to specify the value of the 'Z' flag and had this automatically calculated. This reinforces the notion that the instruction referenced it's own page.